# Sustaining a Model through a view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

If I pass a `Model` to a view, is there an easy way to pass this model through a form on the view to another controller on submission?

For example starting at my `HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    PersonModel pm = new PersonModel() { /* value assignment logic not important */ }
    return View(pm);
}
```

That passes the `PersonModel` to the `Index` view:

```
@model Models.PersonModel
```

On this view I want a `form` to call a `post` method:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="People" asp-action="Continue">
```

And that post method should take the entire model that was passed to it through to the `People` controller `Continue` method.

The only way I know how to persist that model data is by addressing **all** of its properties with inputs (either visible or hidden):

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="People" asp-action="Continue">
    <input asp-for="PersonId" hidden="hidden"/>
    <input asp-for="PersonName" hidden="hidden"/>
    ... etc ...
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

But that's a bit annoying for massive models.

I guess I could write a loop for each property in the `Model`? But I wondered if there was a shortcut way I don't know about where I could write something like

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="People" asp-model=@Model>
```

Please, ignoring the WHY for this example (it's very minimal) - am I just wishful thinking?

(another case could be something like I pass a `List` of `PersonModel` and I wish to pass only the first item that list to the next controller without having to write all the property assignments on the page)

Comment: Couple of options: 1) cache or store in session or a database; 2) keep the model as JSON then repost back without rebuilding a form.

Comment: Actually good idea that I could store the info in the database temporarily, even better if I can cache it, not sure how to do that in an asp net core mvc setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that's different than populating a view model in `[HttpGet]` version of a method and posting back to its `[HttpPost]` version. As long as the model matches what's posted back, the model binding will automatically bind the values into the model for you.

If you have a form that contains all the properties of `PersonModel` with either visible or hidden inputs on the index page and want to post the model to `/people/continue`, the only thing you need to do is to declare `Continue` action in `PeopleController` to take the same view model as parameter:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Continue(PersonModel vm)
{
    ...
}
```

Without knowing your use case in this or what you're trying to accomplish, this should work the way you want it (I just wouldn't do it that way myself).

From what you wrote `<form method="post" asp-controller="People" asp-model=@Model>`, I guess you're looking for a way to carry just the identify of the model to another page? If that's the case, you should, instead of a form, create anchor tags and generate URLs with just the ID of the items:

```
foreach(var personModel in peopleModel)
{
    <a asp-action="continue" asp-controller="people" asp-route-id="@personModel.Id">
        Continue to edit
    </a>
}
```

Then you would need to define a `[HttpGet]` version of `Continue` action method that takes a person ID, looks that up in your storage, and populate a view model for your `Continue` page, just like how you populate `PersonModel` for the index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, it's not quite what I was after though. I didn't want just one value from the model to persist (e.g. `id`) I wanted some shorthand to pass the entire model through. I don't have and didn't want to create a form with all the properties on, that's what I was hoping to avoid - I know this would probably not be much use to a lot of people (because values wouldn't change) but with my combination of `ViewComponent`s and search mechanisms it would help me out a great deal. I think I'll just write a class to cycle through properties and create the html needed.